# Digital Ocean is asking for my Unix password, but once I give it, it closes out

Tags: node.js, reactjs, digital-ocean, create-react-app

I'm having a lot of trouble launching this app. I finally got it to accept the passphrase for my SSH key, but then it hit me with the following response:

```
>You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
>Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-30-generic x86_64)

 >* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 >* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 >* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  >System information as of Sat Sep 15 22:14:30 UTC 2018

  >System load:  0.0               Processes:           83
  >Usage of /:   5.6% of 24.06GB   Users logged in:     0
  >Memory usage: 18%               IP address for eth0: 123.45.678.90
  >Swap usage:   0%

  >Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
  > http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

>24 packages can be updated.
>0 updates are security updates.


>*** System restart required ***
>Last login: Fri Sep 14 18:25:07 2018 from 987.65.432.10
>Changing password for root.
>(current) UNIX password:
>Connection to 123.45.678.90 closed.
```

Firstly, why is it asking for my Unix password.  THis isn't even a Linux/Unix computer.  I'm assuming it just means my computer's password?  Secondly, once I give it my computer's password, it says:

```
>Connection to 123.45.678.90 closed.
```

How am I supposed to proceed?  I'm pretty new to this whole web development thing, so I'm following a tutorial on how to launch an app with Digital Ocean.  This isn't how it is supposed to respond, so I'm really lost here.

I'm using create-react-app with a node back end.

Answer (score 1):

The password being asked here is your droplet's password and yes it is a Linux distribution, namely Ubuntu. Prompt clearly says that you are required to change the password here. So, when the system asks to provide a password just enter your droplet's current password then for the second time provide the password you want.

If you don't know what the password is, then follow [this documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/connect-with-console/). When you ask for a reset DO will email the password to you.