# Digital Ocean Droplet server set up fails at the UNIX key part

Tags: terminal, hosting, digital-ocean

I am trying to set up a Digital Ocean Droplet server and it fails at the UNIX key part.

Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x64, base configuration without anything extra, I have credits multiple what the monthly fee is.

macOS 10.12.6, normal terminal.

I am following the guide of https://www.udemy.com/course/the-ultimate-beginners-guide-to-django-django-2-python-web-dev-website/learn/lecture/9517142#questions

I have read thru a couple of questions/guides, but non of them has answered my question:

- [Digital Ocean is asking for my Unix password, but once I give it, it closes out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349611/digital-ocean-is-asking-for-my-unix-password-but-once-i-give-it-it-closes-out)
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/connection-closes-after-changing-root-password
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/first-time-console-access
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-am-i-being-asked-for-the-current-unix-password-when-logging-in-with-ssh
- this is for windows and I have reset from the control panel already: [Not able to change password of root for digital ocean droplet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56180276/not-able-to-change-password-of-root-for-digital-ocean-droplet)

The guide and I use e-mail password option for the digital Ocean droplet server:
I can SSH my IP Address EX (the 100s just example).:

```
 ssh root@100.100.100.100
```

I can copy and paste and pass the next password question with the email. And that works fine but I cant step thru the following part:

```
Changing password for root.
(current) UNIX password:
```

I always type in the same thing and than it(the 100s just example):
Connection to 100.100.100.100 closed.
than I start the whole thing again and it never asks for anything different

for the guide guy in the 2nd cycle it asks the following, but for me never:

```
Changing password for root.
(current) UNIX password:
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password:
```

Comment: Don't DO disable root password based auth over ssh? I though it was via key file only. Also this is off topic here as its not actually about programming, you should ask over on [sf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted their official support and their 1st answer solved my problem

1.Leveraging the recovery environment to update and troubleshoot issues impacting the root password reset is relatively simple. Starting from the Droplet page, you can turn off the Droplet then access the "Recovery" options to "Boot from recovery ISO". Turning on the Droplet after this will run the Droplet from the recovery environment where you can access the menu via the droplet's Web Console, found within your control panel.

https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/resources/recovery-iso/

Once within the DigitalOcean Recovery ISO, the menu will be available. From this menu, you want to select "Mount your Disk Image" by typing 1 and pushing the Enter/Return key.

After doing this, you will then select "Reset Droplet Root Password" by typing 3 and pushing the Enter/Return key. This will bring you to the Unix passwd prompt, which first asks for your new password. Carefully enter the new password here. After doing so, it will then ask you to re-enter the new password. Once this is completed, you should be brought back to the DigitalOcean Recovery ISO menu.

2.In some cases, issues such as full inodes or full disk utilization can impact the Droplet root password reset process. To verify this condition, you can access the shell option from the menu and check the /mnt details for both disk space and inode usage:

```
  df -h
  df -i
```

If you see that these are at 100% for the /mnt path ( your Droplet disk ) you will want to explore the file system to clear some space before re-attempting to reset the login. These posts may help outline some steps:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125429/tracking-down-where-disk-space-has-gone-on-linux
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117093/find-where-inodes-are-being-used

3.You can also try changing the password via a chroot'd environment. To do this, you will want to select "Attempt to 'chroot' into installed system" by typing 5 and pushing the Enter/Return key. From here, you will be brought into a chroot'd environment of your droplet. You can then use the Linux "passwd" command to change your root password. It will use the same prompts as the "Reset Droplet Root Password" option from the DigitalOcean Recovery ISO.

Once you have completed that, you can boot the Droplet back from the disk. To set this back, simply turn off the Droplet once again and use the Droplet > Recovery options to "Boot from Hard Drive".